# Fetch function in React.js is not working

Tags: reactjs, spring

I have a Spring-Boot application. I want to fetch data with react but i got error message. When i go to localhost:8080/posts , i can get the json result.

This is error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

This is my react code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import reactDom from "react-dom";

function Post(props){
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
    const [postList, setPostList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:8080/posts")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(
            (result) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setPostList(result);
            },
            (error) => {
                setIsLoaded(true);
                setError(error);
            }
        )
    }, [])
    if(error){
        return <div>Error2 !!!</div>
    } else if(!isLoaded){
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    }else{
        return(<ul>
            {postList.map(post => (
                <li>
                    {post.title} {post.text}
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>);
    }
}

export default Post;
```

And this is Post Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/posts")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PostController {

    private final PostService postService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Post> getAllPosts(@RequestParam Optional<Long> userId){
       return postService.getAllPosts(userId);
    }
```

Comment: fetch expects the complete url, not just the relative one. Assuming your Post Controller is running on localhost, your react code should look like fetch("http://localhost:8080/posts")

Comment: "I got error message" isn't as helpful as it could be; perhaps including that error message would make sense. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: There is no error message actually in terminal. @DaveNewton ...

Comment: You said you got an error message.

Comment: I tried with "localhost:8080/posts" but still not working @GregorioPalamà

Comment: Does the request get fired when you open the page? You should see the request in the network tab on your browser's developer tools

Comment: I got an error message now @GregorioPalamà can you look at please

Comment: thank you @GregorioPalamà ı solved it